# How to initiialise the copy constructor for a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, copy-constructor

I've been banging my head against this for at least two hours, there are probably missing gaps in my knowledge here. Basically, I have to write the function for a copy constructor and I can't get it to work no matter what. I'm absolutely overlooking something here because this doesn't seem all that complicated.

```
// Definition default constructor
Members::Members()
{
    members = new map<string, set<string>>;
    numOfMembers = 0;
}

// Definition copy constructor
Members::Members(const Members& mem)
{
    numOfMembers = mem.numOfMembers;
}
```

I can't seem to execute this program at all, it stops at the copy constructor and I'm just not sure where to go from here. Still wrapping my head around the STL maps as well. Would appreciate any help or explanation! Thanks!

**Given Header functions:**

```
class Members
{
    // Overloaded insertion operator (friend)
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Members& mem);


public:
    // Default constructor
    Members();

    // Copy constructor
    Members(const Members& mem);
```

Comment: why the 'new map<string...>' ? can you show the whole content ?

Comment: Sure. Basically, I'm trying to implement the "Members class" and there are three files. Members.h, Members.cpp (which I'm trying to figure out at the moment), and Main.cpp (where I'm testing). The Members.h already has all the member variables I need.


Members is a pointer that points to a dynamic STL map; the first item in the map pair
is a string storing a member, and the second item in the map pair is an STL set of
strings storing a list of friends of that member.


numOfMembers is an int storing the total number of members.

Comment: dynamic STL map does not mean you need 'new', containers in STL are dynamic. Not sure you need number of members, you can check the size of the map for that

Comment: Where does it crash? Can you show the program using these classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a construction, you probably need to create `members` with `new` (which, BTW, there seems to be absolutely no reason to use it here, see farbiondriven's answer). Then you must copy `members` from the other class. This is breakdown:

```
// Definition copy constructor
Members::Members(const Members& mem)
{
    members = new map<string, set<string>>; // Create memebers
    *members = *mem.members; // Copy
    numOfMembers = mem.numOfMembers;
}
```

This can be done in a single step, by using `map`'s copy construction, which creates and copies in one step (see number (3) in [the reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map)):

```
// Definition copy constructor
Members::Members(const Members& mem)
{
    members = new map<string, set<string>>(*mem.members); // Call map's copy constructor
    numOfMembers = mem.numOfMembers;
}
```

Do not forget to `delete members;` on the destructor of your class. Also, please note that this is bad design: you should really use farbiondriven's answer, or at least use an automatic pointer like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Oh MY lord. Thank you so much, I was trying to implement something like that earlier, but my syntax knowledge is gutter trash and I'm still attempting to wrap my head around STL and pointers.

Comment: If this fixes the problem, what did "stops at the copy constructor" mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any special logic in either of the constructors, don't define them, the default ones will be put in place automatically and they do the job just fine.

If you have to define them:

```
// Definition default constructor (note: maps are initialized when you define them)
Members::Members():numOfMembers(0)
{
}

// Definition copy constructor
Members::Members(const Members& mem)
{
    numOfMembers = mem.numOfMembers;
    // if you want the map as well
    members = mem.members;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this out, and unfortunately, it doesn't work still. This is for a class assignment so I was given the Header file and I have to fill out the functions myself. A small snippet of what I'm trying to do is (just kidding, formatting is awful in comments, I'll post it above.)

Comment: I edited your answer to be compatible with your header. you should avoid using 'new'.